# Does this "set intersection" problem have a different name?

Tags: np-complete, sets

I've been back and forth about this one. I have the following theoretical homework problem, which describes the `SET-INTERSECTION` problem. In my homework, it's presented as being NP-complete.

[image: the so called set intersection problem]

Does this problem have a more common name in general Computer Science nomenclature? I'm trying to wrap my head around the definition itself -- and I can't find any resources that refer to the "set intersection problem" with similar parameters to this except in [this pdf](http://research.cs.queensu.ca/~cisc365/2010F/365%20SetIntersectionNPC.pdf). It seems similar to the unit intersection problem [described in a math stackexchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280874/proving-that-unit-intersection-is-np-complete). I also (naively?) think that it might be the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

My actual intent is to understand what the problem describes -- so I'm looking for alternate names and resources that lead in the right direction. I'm not asking for any specific help in proving properties of it -- just understanding what it describes.

Comment: There are a lot of similarities to "[hitting set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation)", which itself is set cover in disguise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no other name for this.